# Story about person/alien manipulating Stock market

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Saw [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48319)  on [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/48015) and having read the answer thought I would post here to see if anybody can identify the story.

> A man crash lands on the earth and must acquire tremendous wealth to
>   rebuild his ship. First he clones himself to improve his abilities and
>   earns a small amount of money. He then "invents" things and grows his
>   wealth by buying stocks on margin and by shorting stocks (for example,
>   shorts ford, invents new car. Ford stock drops. Then he buys ford on
>   margin, sells his invention to ford. Ford stock goes up. Then he
>   rotates through several different industries, later inventing a much
>   better car, repeats the cycle. Broke down the soviet union by loading
>   up obsolete hovercars with obsolete consumer goods and sending them by
>   auto pilot over the border.